# Hibernate empty NOT expression

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, logical-operators

I need to convert my IConditionTree representation into Criterion.

Currently I have implemented logical operator AND and OR and now I need to add also NOT. But this type of criterion is not represented as Junction and needs to be created via Restrictions.not(Criterion criterion). During processing my condition tree I don't know following criterion which must be inserted as input parameter.

```
//initial call
criteria.add(generateNodeCriteria(conditionTree.getRoot(), conditionTree));

private Criterion generateNodeCriteria(IConditionTreeNode node, IConditionTree conditionTree) throws SomeException {
    // Create criteria for condition
    if (node.getCondition() != null) {
        return createConditionCriterion(node.getCondition());
    }

    // Create criteria for logical operator
    if (node.getLogicalOperator() != null) {
        // What logical operator to use?
        Junction junction = null;
        switch (node.getLogicalOperator()) {
        case AND:
            junction = Restrictions.conjunction();
            break;
        case OR:
            junction = Restrictions.disjunction();
            break;
        }

        // Add all direct children of logical operator into conjunction
        for (IConditionTreeNode childNode : conditionTree.getOneLevelChildren(node)) {
            junction.add(generateNodeCriteria(childNode, conditionTree));
        }
        return junction;
    }
    throw new SomeException();
}
```

Is there any way, how to implement NOT logical operator into switch part? What should I change if I want same behaviour of NOT logical operater as for AND/OR operators?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose NOT will have only one child in your tree, so here it goes:

```
//initial call
criteria.add(generateNodeCriteria(conditionTree.getRoot(), conditionTree));

private Criterion generateNodeCriteria(IConditionTreeNode node, IConditionTree    conditionTree) throws SomeException {
    // Create criteria for condition
    if (node.getCondition() != null) {
    return createConditionCriterion(node.getCondition());
}

// Create criteria for logical operator
if (node.getLogicalOperator() != null) {

    boolean addChildren = false;

    // What logical operator to use?
    Junction junction = null;
    switch (node.getLogicalOperator()) {
    case AND:
        junction = Restrictions.conjunction();
        addChildren = true;
        break;
    case OR:
        junction = Restrictions.disjunction();
        addChildren = true;
        break;
    case NOT:
        junction = Restrictions.not(generateNodeCriteria(conditionTree.getOneLevelChildren(node).get(0), conditionTree));
    }

    if (addChildren)
      // Create all children first
      for (IConditionTreeNode childNode : conditionTree.getOneLevelChildren(node)) {
          junction.add(generateNodeCriteria(childNode, conditionTree));
      }

    return junction;
}
throw new SomeException();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about compatibility of Junction and Criterion which comes from Restrictions.not. But it helps me with taking at least some direction. Thx